# Insert hexadecimal values in array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am very new to matlab. I want to store hexadecimal values in array like this

```
P=[0x96,0x97,0x98];
```

But I surfed on google I got no solution for it So first I converted this hexadecimal into decimal so I got array like this

```
P=[150,151,152];
```

Now I am trying to get hexadecimal value of values of P array.

I tried

```
P=[dec2hex(150),dec2hex(151),dec2hex(152)];
```

But when I am trying to print P(1) then instead of 96 I got only 9. I am not understanding this part. How can I get correct result? Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matlab stores hexadecimal number as character arrays (or strings).

So

```
a = dec2hex(150)
```

returns:

```
a = '96'
```

concatenating hexadecimal strings as you do:

```
P=[dec2hex(150),dec2hex(151),dec2hex(152)]
```

returns:

```
P = '969798'
```

Therefore, P(1) = '9'

You probably want to use cell arrays to separately store hex-numbers:

```
P = {dec2hex(150),dec2hex(151),dec2hex(152)};
P{1}
```

returns:

```
P = '96'
```

to retrieve the numeric value, use

```
hex2dec(P{1})
```

Comment: But hex2num does not give same answer. Instead we can use str2num(P{1}) to retrive number

Answer (score 2):

See manual for `dec2hex`

```
dec2hex - Convert decimal to hexadecimal number in string
```

You are getting a `string` and thus `P(1)` only gives you the first character of the string.

Try something like:

```
>> P=[dec2hex(150);dec2hex(151);dec2hex(152)]; % note the ; instead of ,
>> P

P =

96
97
98

>> P(1,:)

ans =

96
```

However, `P` is still an array of characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `arrayfun` with `dec2hex` to work on them elementwise and produce a cell array as the output that uses the format `0x...` -

```
P=[150,151,152] %// Input array
out = arrayfun(@(n) strcat('0x',dec2hex(P(n))),1:numel(P),'Uni',0)
```

Code run -

```
out = 
    '0x96'    '0x97'    '0x98'
```